# How to access the 'previous' element in a C++ list iterator loop?

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I'm trying to access the previously iterated element in a loop going through all the elements of a list.

To be more specific, my loop looks like this:

```
for (iter=list_object.begin(); iter!= list_object_.end(); iter++)
  {
    function_1(*iter);
    function_2(*PREVIOUS_VALUE_IN_THE_LIST);
  }
```

How do I access this previous value in the list?

Comment: Just watch out the first round through the loop!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`std::list` is only bidirecitonally iterable, so you can only move the iterator one position at a time.  You thus need to create a new iterator:

```
iter_copy = iter;
--iter;
```

Obviously, you are responsible for ensuring that a previous element actually exists before you decrement the iterator.

In C++0x, this functionality is neatly wrapped up in the `std::prev` function, which your C++ Standard Library implementation may support.  If not, it looks something like this:

```
template <typename BidiIt>
BidiIt prev(BidiIt x, typename std::iterator_traits<BidiIt>::difference_type n=1)
{
    std::advance(x, -n);
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 24):

An easy way is to simply keep track of the previous element in the for loop, such as:

```
for( list_t::iterator iter=obj.begin(), prev=obj.end(); 
    iter != obj.end(); prev=iter, ++iter )
{
  function_1(*iter);
  if( prev != obj.end() )
    function_2(*prev)
}
```

This will work with iterators which are simply *Forward*, they don't need to be *Bidirectional*.

Comment: What a thoughtful answer. Covered the base case without me even realizing it!

Comment: Note: In this `for(part1; part2; part3){...}`, the comma in the part3(`prev=iter, ++iter`) is an *operator*, while the comma in the part1 is a *separator*.

Answer (score 3):

There are two possibilities.  Either `--itor` or `std::advance(itor, -1)`.

Answer (score 2):

operator-- decrements an iterator.

std::list has a Bidirectional iterator. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/BidirectionalIterator/

Answer (score 0):

The *Forward* iterator loop without inner *if*-statement:

```
if ( auto iter = obj.begin() )
{
  function_1(*iter);
  for( auto prev = iter++; iter != obj.end(); prev = iter++ )
  {
    function_1(*iter);
    function_2(*prev);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::prev(iter)
```

The above gives you the iterator pointing to the previous element. Of course you have to include the header:

```
#include <iterator>
```